How to schedule a Journey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud to run 3 times a day at specific times?
I have a Journey that is triggered via Automation Studio. The Automation Studio includes an SQL query that overwrites a Data Extension, which serves as the Entry Source for the Journey. The data is based on a segment from Data Cloud.
Currently, the Journey is set to run once a day via automation. However, I need the Journey to run 3 times a day at specific times (e.g., 9 AM, 1 PM, and 6 PM) when new contacts join the segment.
Is there a way to set this up in SFMC to ensure the Journey runs at these specific times instead of just once a day? Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!

Why not run the automation hourly and use a verification step to stop it when it's not 9, 1 or 6PM?

@AdamSpriggs what do you think about creating an automation and start it as 9 am and then have 3 script activity which starts the automation (with the SQL and journey) and 3 wait activity 3h between them. The automation will then run only once per day, so it won't consume too much from the automation license limit. My only concern is that automation will be 'running' few hours constantly.

Can we use the below setup to run the automation 3 times a day, but running the automation at specific times 3 times a day seems to be tricky

